# Slick Generic Query return type

Tags: scala, slick

I am making a function that filters a query in slick as following:

```
class Foos(tag: Tag) extends RichTable[Foo](tag, "t_foo") {
    // foo slick mapping
}
```

**working function**

```
object Foos extends PostgresGeneric[Foos, Foo] {
    private def filterQuery(query :Query[Foos,Foos#TableElementType,Seq], searchFilter: FooFilter) = {
        var filteredQuery = query

        if(searchFilter.searchEntity.isDefined) {
          val searchEntity = searchFilter.searchEntity.get

          if(searchEntity.cancelled.isDefined) {
            filteredQuery = filteredQuery.filter(p => p.cancelled === searchEntity.cancelled.get)
          }

          if(searchEntity.nome.isDefined) {
            filteredQuery = filteredQuery.filter(p => p.nome.toLowerCase like "%"+searchEntity.nome.get.toLowerCase()+"%")
          }

          if(searchEntity.localidade.isDefined) {
            filteredQuery = filteredQuery.filter(_.localidade === searchEntity.localidade)
          }
        }

        filteredQuery
    }
}
```

**not working function**

```
object Foos extends PostgresGeneric[Foos, Foo] {
    private def filterQuery(query :Query[Foos,Foos#TableElementType,Seq], searchFilter: FooFilter) = {
        var filteredQuery = query

        if(searchFilter.searchEntity.isDefined) {
          val searchEntity = searchFilter.searchEntity.get

          if(searchEntity.cancelled.isDefined) {
            filteredQuery = filteredQuery.filter(p => p.cancelled === searchEntity.cancelled.get)
          }

          if(searchEntity.nome.isDefined) {
            filteredQuery = filteredQuery.filter(p => p.nome.toLowerCase like "%"+searchEntity.nome.get.toLowerCase()+"%")
          }

          if(searchEntity.localidade.isDefined) {
            filteredQuery = filteredQuery.filter(_.localidade === searchEntity.localidade)
            filteredQuery = filteredQuery.join(tableReferenceFoo2).on(_.foo2 === _.id)
          }
        }

        filteredQuery
    }
}
```

**error message**

```
Error:(165, 76) type mismatch;
 found   : scala.slick.lifted.Query[(model.db.entity.Foos, model.db.entity.Foos2),(model.db.entity.Foo, model.db.entity.Foos2#TableElementType),Seq]
    (which expands to)  scala.slick.lifted.Query[(model.db.entity.Foos, model.db.entity.Foos2),(model.db.entity.Foo, model.db.entity.Foo2),Seq]
 required: slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple.Query[model.db.entity.Foos,model.db.entity.Foo,Seq]
    (which expands to)  scala.slick.lifted.Query[model.db.entity.Foos,model.db.entity.Foo,Seq]
        filteredQuery = filteredQuery.join(tableReferenceFoo2).on(_.Foo2 === _.id)
```

The first code works because the resulting query has always the same type after the filtering. It fails after the join, because the type changes.

**Porblem:**

this function works OK until I need to perform a join with another table.

So, how could I type this Query instance in a way it would accept a type that would mount any kind of query? Is it possible?

Comment: Perhaps the compiler can't work out what's the type of your function. Have you tried to define the return type of it?

Comment: I don't really know the return type. It could be Query[Foos,Foos#TableElementType,Seq] OR Query[(Foos, Foos2, FoosN), (Foos#TableElementType,Foos2#TableElementType, FoosN#TableElementType),Seq] if it has joins

Comment: Can you include an example which works and an example which fails, with the compiler message?

Comment: What's the compiler message on the failing example?